# Is it OK to use the version 4.0.2 of rails to read the ebook Agile Web Development with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning Rails and I beginning to read the ebook Agile Web Development with Rails 4 and I have installed and configured in my Mac Os X the rails 4.0.2 and I see in the book who recommends to install the version 4.0.0.
I think the version 4.0.2 is better and I want to do all the ebook with this version but I have fear if I'll have problems because of this?
Is it OK if I'm continuing the ebook with the version 4.0.2, or should I install the 4.0.0?

Comment: RoR is versioned as `major.minor.revision`. Different revisions with the same major/minor number should only be "feature fixes". See the [release notes](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/): "I am happy to announce that Rails 4.0.x has been released. This is a *bug fix release* and includes more than 460 commits."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences between version 4.0.0 and 4.0.2 will be minimal.

I wouldn't worry about it.

Edit: added 4.0.x release notes

```
Rails 4.0 Release History

Rails 4.0.2 was released December 3, 2013 with security fixes. See Rails 3.2.16 and 4.0.2 have been released!.
Rails 4.0.1 was released November 1, 2013 with performance gains and many bug fixes. See Rails 4.0.1 has been released!.
Rails 4.0.0 was released June 25, 2013. See Rails 4.0: Final version released!.
```

Comment: Thank's to reply Peter!
I have a fear because in the ebook talk about this version and I think it's ok the versions I have, but I don't want to see a problem because of this when I reading the ebook.
Regards!

Comment: @user2993674 Differences in minor versions rarely change the system in visible ways. The changes between 4.0 and 4.0.2 are bug fixes, performance fixes and security fixes, added to reply.  Nothing that you will notice doing the ebook exercises.

Comment: Thank's for reply Peter!